# Create azure serverless function with parameter

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am trying to create a simple function that will take a parameter on the get and return a list of categories based on that parameter.

However, I cannot find any useful documentation about routing or passing through parameters so this is what I have - I just need a pointer in how to access the website parameter (and if the route is correct)

```
public static class GetCategoriesCRUDFunction
{
    [FunctionName("CategoriesFunction")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "{website}")]HttpRequestMessage request, TraceWriter log) // is this how to set up a route or do I need to do attribute routing?
    {
        IService service = new Service();

        var categories = await service.GetCategories(website);  // how do I get this website parameter from the querystring - do I need to use something like httpcontext?

        return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, categories);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. To actually get the value from the querystring, add the parameter to the `Run` method:

```
[FunctionName("CategoriesFunction")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "{website}")] HttpRequestMessage request, 
    string website, 
    TraceWriter log)
```

You might want to add something in the route... By default, all HttpTriggered functions have a route prefix of `api`. So you could, for instance, have the route be `Route = "categories/{website}"` so the URL will be `https://<function_app_url>/api/categories/<websitename>`